# 'tuple' object is not callable in python, jupyter

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, jupyter

I receive an error in my very naive code in python:

```
mylist = ("a" , "b" , "c")
mylist
mylist
('a', 'b', 'c')
mylist2 =(1, 2, 3,4,5)
mylist2
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
mylist(0)
mylist2(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8dec3b0af63c> in <module>
----> 1 mylist(0)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

mylist2(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a2be157acb8f> in <module>
----> 1 mylist2(0)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you want `mylist[0]` to index the tuple and get its first item?

Comment: Check out the tutorial [Tuples and sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: I think the answer is to run through some basic tutorials. You'll learn faster working through examples than asking here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Tuple' object is not callable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775032/tuple-object-is-not-callable-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly are tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2488522/2745495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need brackets instead of parentheses:

```
mylist2[0]
```